# Python - Compare duplicate values in two csv files and write the row in a separate csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 `.csv` files that have thousands of rows of data (product inventory from vendors). I need to find duplicates and delete the item with the higher price.

The issue is prices contain decimals. The following code is the closest I have come based on what I need done:

```
with open('vendor1.csv', 'r') as venOne, open('vendor2.csv', 'r') as venTwo, open('filtered.csv', 'w') as outFile:

    z = csv.reader(venOne, delimiter = ',')
    m = csv.reader(venTwo, delimiter = ',')
    w = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter = ',')

    zupc = {row[5] for row in z}    #UPC is in column 5
    mupc = {row[5] for row in m}

    zprice = {row[9] for row in z}  #Price is in column 9
    mprice = {row[7] for row in m}  #Price is in column 7

    for row in z:
        if row[5] in mupc and row[9] < mprice:
            w.writerow(row)
        else:
            if row[5] not in mupc:
                w.writerow(row)

    #Do the same for m
```

I am using `Python 2.x`.

In the end this will be ran using a `cron` job. All the data is on a remote shared server.

One caveat is I am unable to use `pandas` (which would have saved me a lot of time with other various scripts I wrote). The only import modules available are the ones that come standard with python and adding add-on modules is out of the question (that is, without spending much more money upgrading to a dedicated server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should probably use `dict` and not `set`. About the prices, you can try to cast them to `decimal`.

Try this code and let me know if that helps you:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def write_cheaper_items(output, rows, this_prices, other_prices):
    for row in rows:
        upc = row[5]
        if upc not in other_prices or this_prices[upc] < other_prices[upc]:
            output.writerow(row)

with open('vendor1.csv', 'r') as venOne, open('vendor2.csv', 'r') as venTwo, open('filtered.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    z = csv.reader(venOne, delimiter = ',')
    m = csv.reader(venTwo, delimiter = ',')
    w = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter = ',')

    # these dicts will have the UPC as keys and their prices as values
    z_prices = {
        row[5]: Decimal(row[9])
        for row in z}
    m_prices = {
        row[5]: Decimal(row[7])
        for row in m}

    write_cheaper_items(w, z, z_prices, m_prices)
    write_cheaper_items(w, m, m_prices, z_prices)
```